# Django rest framework how to ignore an object within a serializer method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I'm using celery with django / django-rest-framework.

And I'm using tensorflow as well.

Now for a session problem with tensorflow, I need to initialise sessions before the celery workers are called.

Thus, I tried to do it from the view, but then I have to initialise a class containing a specific script.

It looks like that:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save(
        state=app_models.Video.STATE_PROCESSING_QUEUED,
        agency=self.request.user.agency
    )

    # Extracted from the worker to be initialise before the worker is instanciated
    sess_det = tf.Session()
    sess_clf = tf.Session()
    ED = Emotion_Detector(sess_det, sess_clf)

    app_tasks.process_video.delay(instance.id, ED) # Celery worker

    sess_det.close()
    sess_clf.close()
```

which is within a class based view:

```
class VideoProcessingViewSet(
    CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin,
    GenericViewSet
):
....
```

But then, when I try to run celery I have this error:
`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'Emotion_Detector' is not JSON serializable`

How can I ignore the Emotion_Detector? Is there a way not to serialise it?

Comment: This is not really a problem with DRF, but with celery; either rewrite the task so all its arguments can be serialized to JSON (if possible), or use pickle as serializer in celery (security risks, [read the documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html#serializers))

Comment: Well, at first the Emotion_Detector was in celery. So I don't see how it can come from celery.

Comment: Your first hint should be that the exception is raised by kombu, a messaging library used by celery.

Comment: Ok true, but there is no ways for me to have the Emotion_detector and the function called from it within the worker to be entirely serialized to JSON... I'll try the pickle thing ;(